# How to script Gradle in order to publish shadowjar into Artifactory

Tags: java, gradle, build

I am using shadowJar in my java project.
I would like to push the outcome into artifactory.

My gradle script look like this, I am not sure how to connect the dots:

```
shadowJar {
    baseName = 'com.mycompany.myapp'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'myapp.starter'
    }
}


  ]
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'


    // rep for the project
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.company:8081/artifactory/libs-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${repo_user}"
                password = "${repo_password}"
            }
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.company:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot'
            credentials {
                username = "${repo_user}"
                password = "${repo_password}"
            }
        }

}


publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I code gradle to take the shadowjar file?

thanks,
ray.

Comment: Do you want to publish the shadow jar in addition to normal jar? Or replace it?

Comment: publish the shadow jar into artifactory, thats it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `publication` section determines what you're publishing using the `maven-publish` plugin.

In your current config, `from components.java` is going to publish the default jar artifact of your project and artifact `sourceJar` publishes the sourceJar. In order to publish a different jar, you need to modify (or add a new) publication.

```
shadowJar {
  baseName = 'myproject-shadow'
  classifier = ''
}

publishing {
  publications {
    shadow(MavenPublication) {
      from components.shadow
      artifactId = 'myproject-shadow'
    }
  }
}
```

The version used in the name of the jar comes from project.version.

Comment: but the problem is that I need to change the version name from RELEASE to snapshop else I get 409. jenkins is running this and I dont want manually change the gradle.build script whenever I switch from snapshop to release. any idea how to make it dynamic?        eg:     artifacts = ["com.company.app-1.0-RELEASE-all.jar", sourceJar]

Comment: That's an entirely different question isn't it? The dynamically chosen artifact naming should happen in your shadowJar task. The publication just picks up whatever named jar the shadowJar task produced. What plugin are you using to create shadowJar?

Comment: updating my answer anyway.

Comment: I am using com.github.johnrengelman.shadow plugin. How would you dynamically change the shadowJar from release and snapshot(assume that I am using jenkins to do that job - depends on which job I am using diff strategy (snapshot or release)

Comment: Is there a variable that determines whether current release is snapshot out release?

Comment: No.. but I guess ill need one by this comment. could you show me an example how to do so?

Comment: btw: when I refactor to your answer I got: Task 'publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository' not found in root project

Comment: I changed the publication name to `shadow`, so the task likely changes to `publishShadowPublicationToMavenRepository`. Run `gradle tasks` for a complete list of actual tasks.

Comment: How do you tell if your current release is Snapshot or Release?

Comment: I managed to fix it. but I still have probs with the final jar name. as suggested I opened new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155345/how-to-change-the-jar-filename-when-upload-to-artifactory-via-gradle    would be great if you could take a look. thank you.

Answer (score 17):

It's a bit late, but I'd like to show you how I got it to work. Maybe it helps someone stumbling across this question as I did:

**build.gradle.kts:**

```
plugins {
    java
    `maven-publish`
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "5.1.0"
}
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            from(components["java"])
            artifact(tasks["shadowJar"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
          /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

The example above is written in Kotlin, if you prefer Groovy, you would need to write this instead:

**build.gradle:**

```
publishing {
  publications {
    shadow(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
      artifact shadowJar
    }
  }
}
```

(found it here: https://libraries.io/github/johnrengelman/shadow)

Answer (score 7):

The API has changed in the `shadow` plugin, this works for me with `com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1`: http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#publishing_shadow_jars

```
5. Publishing Shadow JARs
5.1. Publishing with Maven-Publish Plugin
The Shadow plugin will automatically configure the necessary tasks 
in the presence of Gradle’s maven-publish plugin. The plugin provides
the component method from the shadow extension to configure the 
publication with the necessary artifact and dependencies in the 
POM file.

Publishing a Shadow JAR with the Maven-Publish Plugin
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

publishing {
  publications {
    shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
      project.shadow.component(publication)
    }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://repo.myorg.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to get Gradle to publish to our Nexus repo using the shadow plugin and the maven-publish plugin:  (run publish task: "gradle publish")

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow
            groupId 'myGroupId'
            artifactId 'myArtifactId'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/stuff"
            credentials {
                username = "${System.env.NEXUS_USERNAME}"
                password = "${System.env.NEXUS_PASSWORD}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you gotten this technique to work with `id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.1.0'`?

Comment: @GlennMcElhoe We are current using version 5.0.0, so I would assume it works with 5.1.0, but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Artifactory Gradle Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin)? This can help you with what you need, resolving and deploying artifacts from and to Artifactory.

You can publish using the plugin by omitting the 'artifactory' plugin from a project that does not publish anything. Note that this does not apply to the root project that contains the convention object, and so, requires the plugin to be applied.
Activate the corresponding artifactoryPublish Gradle task manually for each project to which you wish to apply the plugin. 
For example in our  Gradle project example you can run:
./gradlew clean api:artifactoryPublish shared:artifactoryPublish

Comment: I dont understand how to publish release.. I just managed snapshots

Comment: The same way you publish your Snapshots just make sure you refer your publish to the Release repository. In case that you will try to publish release to snapshot repository you will probably get error 409.

Comment: yes but how to refer your publish to the Release repository?

Comment: change the clientConfig.publisher.repoKey = 'integration-libs' to the realese repository.

Comment: " 
but the problem is that I need to change the version name from RELEASE to snapshop else I get 409. jenkins is running this and I dont want manually change the gradle.build script whenever I switch from snapshop to release. any idea how to make it dynamic? eg: artifacts = ["com.company.app-1.0-RELEASE-all.jar", sourceJar] – rayman 2 hours ago "

Usually Release artifact are not listed as com.company.app-1.0-RELEASE-all.jar but com.company.app-1.0-all.jar 
Can you please share why you are naming your artifacts as you wrote?

Comment: you right my mistake..but still how i am going to make this dynamic?

Comment: As far as I know you can set the release version as a variable and pass it as a parameter when running the build. But I'm not 100% sure. This needs to be tested.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers take multimodule projects into consideration. For a multimodule project, no one configures publication for every single module; instead, it's done in the root build file.

Also, in a multimodule project, usually only one module needs to be shadowed as an executable JAR. It makes no sense to apply the shadow plugin to every module.

Here's how to achieve all of the above using Kotlin DSL:

In the subproject:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
}
...
project.tasks.findByName("jar")?.enabled = false

tasks.withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    archiveClassifier.set("")
    manifest {
        attributes(mapOf("Main-Class" to "com.mycompany.MainClass"))
    }
}
```

In the root project:

```
publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        afterEvaluate {
            val shadowJar = tasks.findByName("shadowJar")
            if (shadowJar == null) from(components["java"])
            else artifact(shadowJar)
        }
        artifact(kdocJar)
        artifact(sourcesJar)
    }
    ...
}
```

The key is the `afterEvaluate` configuration. See [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:deferred_configuration) for details.

The `project.shadow.component(publication)` everyone keeps talking about doesn't exist in the root project and will not compile in a Kotlin DSL. It's the `ShadowExtension` that only exists in the project where the plugin is applied.

Comment: It is not entirely true that there is only one publication for a multi-module project. If I have a multi-module that contains one library jar to share with clients and one server jar to deploy which also uses that library, I would require two independent publications. I wonder if the error that I am seeing of a duplicated `<dependencies/>` tag when trying to publish the shadowed server jar is due to my predicament.

Comment: @hanzo2001 No one said there is only one publication for a MM project. What I said is that you configure the publication only once. You can publish as many artifacts as you need, no one is stopping you.

Comment: I am going to try this out. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this:

### build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    `maven-publish`
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        val publication = create<MavenPublication>("shadow")
        project.shadow.component(publication)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you deploy the Shadow plugin, you can then run the `publishShadowPublicationToMavenLocal` and `publishShadowPublicationToMavenRepository` gradle tasks.

These is the same as the corresponding tasks from the [Maven publishing gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) such as `publishToMavenLocal`, but it publishes the shadow jar instead.