# How to change the jar filename when upload to artifactory via gradle

Tags: gradle, build, artifactory

I am using gradle in order to upload jar to artifactory.
I managed to do it however I am trying to change the jar filename but it doesnt really let me.

I am using shadowJar to package. this is how I do it:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'



    shadowJar {
        classifier = ''
        baseName = 'com.mycompany.app-all'
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mycompany.app.main.starter'
        }
    }


publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow

            groupId 'com.mycompany'
            artifactId "app"
            version "${build_version}"
        }
    }
}
```

Now if build_version=2.1 than the dirs on artifactory will look like this:

http://repo.address:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/2.1/**app-2.1.jar**

I would like to keep the folder structure but change the jar filename(as defined in shadowJar)

and to have it this way:

http://repo.address:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/2.1/**com.mycompany.app-all.jar**

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jar task default naming convention is

```
[baseName]-[appendix]-[version]-[classifier].[extension]
```

If you set just the basename, the remaining values get appended to it. To override, set `archiveName` instead of `baseName`

```
shadowJar {
    ...
    archiveName = 'com.mycompany.app-all'
    ...
}
```

To change naming on what artifactory is publishing:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow

            groupId 'com.mycompany'
            artifactId 'com.mycompany.app-all' //<-- changed here
            version ''                         // and here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it didnt do the trick. I am still having the following file in artifactory: http://repo.address:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/2.3/app-2.3.jar

Comment: The archiveName changes the filename as expected - but only locally! as soon as it published, it changes into the format that I specified below: Uploading: com/mycompany/app/2.4/app-2.4.jar to repository remote

Comment: When I check the jar on artifactory I payed attention that it excluded everything under my web/resources module. Any idea how to refactor the code and include it?

Comment: @rage did you get it to work - care to share a working version?

Comment: I am also lookingf or a similar solution - to change my tar file name as that's expected by a legacy Teamcity deploy job. Any one got a solution for this?

Comment: This question is specific to the shadow jar plugin and is several years old. Please post a new question with more details about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer, to modify the jar name to be published to artifactory , just adding the below to publishing worked for me.

```
artifactId = 'ChangedJarName'
```